# Internet connectivity for Azure VMs behind an application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I have 2 VMs on Azure that needs internet connectivity, there is no public ip address on the VMs, I have an application gateway providing access to the applications on the VMs but applications need to send data to other servers and send e-mails. How do I provide internet access to those VMs without adding public IPs on them? Is it possible to use application gateway as a NAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VM's in Azure have internet access by default, there is no need to add any sort of NAT gateway or similar (like you have to in AWS).

Comment: But this is because of the public IP addres correct? I have another envioronment that has a VM without a public IP address (but in this case internet access is not required) and it does not have internet access also.

Comment: @user3670112 no, VMs without a public IP have internet access. You do not need a public IP for this. If  you are seeing connection issues you may want to look at your NSG's

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will check them.